# Images disappear when i include masonry jquery script

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

I'm trying to use the masonry script to get the images as gallery without any gap according to different sized images. I tried the jQuery way initialize but i can't able to see the images when the script is initialized. but if i didn't do the script initialize i mean not using masonry i can able to see the images.

I think Script applying `position:absolute` i don't have idea of what going on.

**CODE:**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {                  
    var $container = $('#p-grid');
    // initialize
    $container.masonry({
        columnWidth: 200,
        itemSelector: '.photos'
    });
    var msnry = $container.data('masonry');
});
```

Why is this happening? What is the problem here? Am i doing it correctly?

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CTRj7/1/)

Answer (score 1):

try something like this,[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/CTRj7/2/)

```
.pic {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
position: relative
}

.pic img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks +1. can't be done in percentage instead of px @rajesh kakawat

Comment: may be it can be done but you have to specify width of parent container and image width

Comment: Width of the parent container(`#p-grid`) is 100%. Even it making this.

Comment: parent width should be in px #p-grid{
    width:500px;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
}